# Marklogic out of the box rest API transform query

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using out of the box ML REST API `POST v1/search`, and I am using `transform?` parameter to transform the results produced. But I also want to manipulate the string `q` that is sent to the endpoint. Is there anything like `transform-query` or something that will be called to transform the query string. I understand we can write a custom endpoint to do this, but I want to avoid if this can be done out of the box endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is wrote a custom web service which handles the transform query, but I also like all the params that the out-of-box rest api does, so I copied the xquery code of the out-of-box.. Following is what I did. In my case I am doing just query expansion

```
let $search:= map:get($params,"q")
let $qexpand := repo-searchLib:queryExpand($search)
let $_ := map:put($params, "q", $qexpand)
let $headers   := eput:get-request-headers()
let $env       := eput:response-callback-map(eput:response-type-callback#1)
let $response := searchmodq:search-post($headers,$params, $env, xdmp:get-request-body(eput:get-content-format($headers,$params)))
let $has-matches := map:get($env, "has-matches")
return
    if (exists($response)) then $response
    else if ($has-matches) then ()
    else xdmp:set-response-code(404,"Not Found")
```

Do any of you think that there might be something that I might be missing ? presently this seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 2):

While it's not supported in /v1/search, I think this is a reasonable thing to do in a middle tier - e.g. a Java or NodeJS layer on top of the REST API.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  At present, there is no support for a transform on the query input to perform query expansion and other query manipulations.

A resource service extension would be the current recommended approach, calling either cts:parse() / cts:search() / search:resolve() or search:search() with the modified query.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Depending on need, a rest extension would be recommended indeed, particularly if you are looking for content-driven query expansion.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is expressible by adding to the search criteria (rather than modifying the string query), you could use a combined query with /v1/search to combine the original string query with a structured query that expresses the additional criteria.

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_69918